# Вид ошибки (строчная-прописная буква)

Tags: орфография, типы-ошибок

Написание слова со строчной буквы, когда следовало бы писать с прописной, следует отнести к орфографической ошибке?

Answer (score 3):

Совершенно верно.

**Орфографическая ошибка** — это ошибка, возникающая в результате нарушения орфографической нормы.

**Орфографические нормы** русского языка — это правила обозначения слов на письме.
Они включают в себя следующее:
1) правила обозначения звуков буквами;
2) правила слитного, дефисного и раздельного написания слов;
3) **правила употребления прописных (заглавных) букв**;
4) правила переноса слов.

**С прописной буквы** пишутся собственные имена и наименования, а также первое слово в начале каждого предложения. Остальные слова пишутся со строчной буквы.

Если Вы напишете "город на **н**еве" (или Санкт-**п**етербург) или начнете предложение со строчной буквы, то эти ошибки будут считаться орфографическими.

[Орфоэпические и орфографические нормы русского языка](http://theoldtree.ru/inostrannye_yazyki_i_yazykoznanie/orfoepicheskie_i_orfograficheskie_normy.php)

Comment: А являются ли орфографические ошибки грамматическими?

Comment: Нет. Грамматические ошибки — это неcоблюдение норм слово- и формообразования, норм синтаксической связи между словами в словосочетании и предложении. (http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=10.9) _Я приехал в **москва.**_ Здесь две ошибки: орфографическая — строчная "м"; грамматическая — неправильная форма (падеж) существительного.